# opencv c and c++ interface conversion table

Tags: c++, c, opencv

i'l learning opencv with c++ and so i'm trying to use new c++ interface. but a lot of code i found on internet is based on old c interface.

for example i fond a lot of algorithm based on

```
IplImage, cvCvtPixToPlane, cvThreshold
```

and i have to translate them in

```
cv::Mat, cv::threshold, ..
```

in [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/introduction.html) (i think the official manual) i haven't find anything of really complete.

and each time i have to google for get the right conversion in the new c++ interface.
where can i find a conversion table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try OpenCV manuals, It seems they are the best way to find equivalent functions.

Version 2.1 : http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs4243/doc/opencv.pdf

All C,C++ and python API is available as single pdf, so you can just search for function names to find equivalent in C or C++

Version 2.3 : https://shimcv.googlecode.com/files/opencv2refman.pdf

Online version of 2.3 : http://opencv.itseez.com/

Comment: yeah Opencv 2.3 does the trick, for example here: http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html there is **c**, **c++** and **python** signatures

Answer (score 1):

The [cheatsheet](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/opencv_cheatsheet.pdf) doesn't have conversions but is the most useful documentation I've found and used!